# Increase bootstrap custom-control custom-switch size only with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm trying to increase the size of a custom-control custom-switch element only with css but it's not working.

My custom-switch now is the default size like in this example but I need it to be bigger in size:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/

We are not using scss in our project and every solution I found for this was a scss solution thats why I'm looking for a pure vanilla css solution.

My code for the custom-switch is similar to this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A simple idea to change size

```
.custom-control-label::before ,.custom-control-label::after{width:20px; height:20px}
```

> A detail one

```
.custom-control-label { // added for alignment with the switch
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
  left: -2.25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 3.5rem;    // it was 1.75rem before. Sliding way is longer than before.
  pointer-events: all;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
  top: calc(0.25rem + 2px);
  left: calc(-2.25rem + 2px);
  width: calc(2rem - 4px);   // it was calc(1rem - 4px) before. Oval is bigger than before.
  height: calc(2rem - 4px);  // it was calc(1rem - 4px) before. Oval is bigger than before.
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  border-radius: 2rem; //   it was 0.5rem before. Oval is bigger than before.
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.5rem); //translateX(0.75rem);
  transform: translateX(1.5rem); //translateX(0.75rem);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To simply change the size, I think one can scale on the `custom-control-input` class.

```css
.custom-control-input {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Comment: Easiest solution

Comment: this worked the best for what I needed. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is an overkill while the second stopped the animation for me for bootstrap v4.6.

Here is my solution for 2x scale:

```
/* Positioning the enlarged switch */

.custom-switch > .custom-control-label {
    padding-left: 1.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

/* Sync the animation for switch knob */

.custom-switch > .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) translateX(0.75rem);
    transform: scale(2) translateX(0.75rem);
}

/* Enlarge and position the switch knob */

.custom-switch > .custom-control-label::after {
    left: -1.75rem;
    transform: scale(2);
}

/* Enlarge and position the switch socket */

.custom-switch > .custom-control-label::before {
    left: -1.50rem;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```